# Return File Name Causing Issue

Tags: python

I'm looping through a directory to read in a series of csv files into a single pandas dataframe. In one of the csv's its throwing an error. I can work through this one by one and figure out which one is causing the error, but I assume there must be some way to build in error handling that would print out the file that is causing the issue, however I'm not sure how to implement something like that.

Any advice appreciated, code below:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\PATH\TestCSVs' 
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

master_df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)

print(master_df.shape)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to catch the error?

Comment: @quamrana I'm very loosely familiar with the idea of try/except. I attempted to implement it as the following:

try:
    path = r'C:\Users\johnsonm\OneDrive - American Health Information Management Association\Work - H\SQL Work\Help Desk Requests\INC-6267\CleanedData\TestCSVs'                     # use your path
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent

    master_df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
except:
    print(f)

I get "name 'f' is not defined".

Comment: @MPJ567 the error in your comment is an issue with your try/except. In `except: print(f)`, `f` is not defined, since `f` in only defined within `pd.concat`. I would change the one-line `pd.concat` into a for loop and then use try/except there. In the for loop, you can have `try: ... except: print(f) continue`.

Comment: Please update your question with the `try: except:` code you have tried and the error traceback.